# Can I walk along the ocean from Cannon Beach, Oregon, to Hug Point or Adair Point?

Tags: usa, beaches, walking, oregon

Satellite view on Google maps suggests that I can go to the Hug Point but not past it. Or does everything depend on the tide?
If so, and if this isn't considered offtopic, then how to determine when the tide is low enough? I can find the tide information, but I can't "read" it so to speak.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It appears to be possible at low tide, according to the website for [Hug Point State Recreation Site:](https://stateparks.oregon.gov/index.cfm?do=park.profile&parkId=137)

> North of the parking area at low tide you may walk along the original stagecoach road, still harboring the wheel ruts carved into the rock.  Pioneers traveling around this headland had to hug the point carefully, even at low tide. Thus, the point and the park are both aptly named Hug Point.

In addition, [this photo-sphere on Google Maps](https://goo.gl/maps/7Ctw5uxYcahBouGn7) was clearly taken by someone walking around the point, as were several others nearby on the map.

As far as tide information goes, the graph linked to from that site is fairly easy to read.  It is not clear from the website whether the tide needs to be particularly low to be able to pass around the point;  but I suspect that if you called  one or both of the numbers listed on the official website above, you might be able to find out.

Answer (score 6):

Supplemental info to Michael Seifert's good answer

> how to determine when the tide is low enough?

1. Call the recreation park and ask at what water level it's safe/dry
   to walk.
2. Use the tide table to determine which times are safe
3. Plan your hike so that you are at hug point at a safe time. Keep track of time.

> I can find the tide information, but I can't "read" it so to speak.

You can find tide tables online. See for example https://tides.willyweather.com/or/tillamook-county/hug-point.html

The curve shows the water level as a function of time relative to the "average low tide".  There are 2 high tides and two low tides every day and they are about 6 hours apart. The times do change a little every day, so you need to look them up. The difference between high and low tide can be more than 6 feet which is the difference between dry feet and potential drowning so it's important to pay attention.

Hug Point appears to have a somewhat unusual tide pattern, at least at the moment: the two low tides each day have very different water levels and the morning one is not very low.

Example: if the park tells you: it's safe to walk there when the water level is 2 feet or less then on Sunday Dec 5, you would have to be at Hug Point between 7pm and 12:30am the next morning. That's the only times on Sunday where the water is 2ft or below.

Comment: It is common on the West coast of the US to have two low tides of different heights each day.  The 0 point for tide height is MLLW-Mean Low Low Water, which means you find the lower low tide each day over a long period and average them.  I understand the East coast has two low tides of about the same height each day, which has to do with the fact that the Pacific basin is larger than the Atlantic basin and can support a 24 hour wave.